# Double loop takes time

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a script which takes a lot of time and can't finish so far after 2 days...
I parsed 1 file into 2 dictionaries as the following:

```
gfftree = {'chr1':[(gene_id, gstart, gend),...], 'chr2':[(gene_id, gstart, gend),...],...}
TElocation = {'chr1':[(TE_id, TEstart, TEend),...], 'chr2':[(TE_id, TEstart, TEend),...],...}
```

.

--The aim is to find TE_id whose TEstart or TEend or both are located between gene_id' gstart and gend in each chr(key).

## The above should be changed to "find TE_id whose range(TEstart, TEend) overlaps with any gene_id's range(gstart,gend)"

Here is my code:

```
TE_in_TSS = []
for TErange in TElocation[chromosome]:
    TE_id, TEstart, TEend = TErange
    for item in gfftree[chromosome]:
        gene, gstart, gend = item       
        if len(list(set(range(int(gstart),int(gend)+1)) & set(range(int(TEstart),int(TEend)+1)))) > 0:
            TE_in_TSS.append((gene, TE_id, TEstart, TEend))
        else:
            pass
```

So far I'm sure this loop is fine with small data, but when it comes to bigger one like 800,000 TE_id and 4,000 gene_id, it takes time...and I don't know if it could finish...

Comment: Hmm. Very much a case where the data structures matter. In languages where you can efficiently (amortized-constant-time) get a subset of a dictionary between a limited set of keys, I can think of some fairly obvious optimizations, but I don't know if those are possible in Python.

Comment: That said, building a realized set of integers in each range is definitely very, very inefficient. No question that removing that and writing the logic long-form would be for the better.

Comment: I think you can use multithreads to speed it up. Run many searches in parallel

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions.

Comment: What should be the result if two consecutive genes are `(3, 12, 42)` and `(4, 55, 77)` and we have this TE: `('c', 40, 56)`? Do we have two inserts (`(3, 'c', 40, 56)` and `(4, 'c', 40, 46)`) or just one (`(3, 'c', 40, 56)`)?

Comment: Did you really mean "TEstart or TEend or both are located between gstart and gend"? Or did you mean "The range from TEstart to TEend at least partially overlaps the range from gstart to gend"? Your code appears to be doing the latter; that is, if `TEstart = 2` and `TEend = 10`, do you consider that a pass for a `gstart = 5` and `gend = 7`; neither `TE` bound occurs in the `g` range, but the ranges overlap.

Comment: @ Craig Burgler, I expect the result to have both inserts

Comment: @ ShadowRanger 27, I mean "The range from TEstart to TEend at least partially overlaps the range from gstart to gend". Thanks for notifying  that TE range might be over gene...

Comment: Python is really slow and when you have bigish data it is probably advisable to use something like R. I had some 10X transcriptome (roughly 500mb) data and even using pandas it really wasn't manageable in python. And by that I mean pandas read up the data just fine, but when I called the co-variance method on the data frame it went away and never came back...

The only way that python can handle large tasks is by divide and conquer. Often enough I'll write python script will write out a bash script that kicks of a number of instances of a second python script to get heavy lifting done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP approach is `O(n*m)`, where `n` is the number of genes and `m` is the number of TEs. Rather than test each gene against each TE as in the OP, this approach leverages the ordered nature of the genes and TEs, and the specified rules of matching, to look at each gene and TE only once, except for the gene look-ahead described in `3.` below. This approach is `O(n + m)` provided that the average gene look-ahead is small relative to `n`. The sequence in which each gene and TE is visited is described by:

1. After we finish testing the current TE against the current gene, we
   get the next TE.
2. When the current TE's start position is past the current gene's end
   position, we get the next gene until it's not.
3. If we find a matching TE/gene pair, we test each successive gene
   against the current TE until there is no match, leaving the current
   gene unchanged.

---

```
def get_TE_in_TSS(genes, TEs):
    TE_in_TSS = []
    gene_pos, TE_pos = 0, 0
    gene_count, TE_count = len(genes), len(TEs)
    while gene_pos < gene_count:
        while (TE_pos < TE_count) and (TEs[TE_pos][1] <= genes[gene_pos][2]):
            match_gene_pos = gene_pos
            while (match_gene_pos < gene_count) and (TEs[TE_pos][2] >= genes[match_gene_pos][1]):
                TE_in_TSS.append((genes[match_gene_pos][0], TEs[TE_pos][0],
                                  TEs[TE_pos][1], TEs[TE_pos][2]))
                match_gene_pos += 1 # look ahead to see if this TE matches the next gene
            TE_pos += 1
        gene_pos += 1
    return TE_in_TSS
```

---

*performance*, as reported by OP:

```
1 second (compared to 2 days + for OP code) for 801,948 TEs, 6,007 genes
```

---

*test data:*

```
genes = (('HTR3A', 7, 9), ('ADAMTSL4', 10,100), ('THSD4',2000, 2800), ('PAPLN', 2850, 3000))
TEs = (('a', 10, 11), ('b', 13, 17), ('c', 50, 2500), ('d', 2550, 2700),
       ('e', 2800, 2900), ('f', 9999, 9999)) 
TE_in_TSS = get_TE_in_TSS(genes, TEs)
print(TE_in_TSS)
```

*Output:*

```
[('ADAMTSL4', 'a', 10, 11), ('ADAMTSL4', 'b', 13, 17), ('ADAMTSL4', 'c', 50, 2500), 
 ('THSD4', 'c', 50, 2500), ('THSD4', 'd', 2550, 2700), ('THSD4', 'e', 2800, 2900), 
 ('PAPLN', 'e', 2800, 2900)]
```

---

Note that the first 9 comments on this post refer to a more efficient `O(n * m)` approach that became outdated by clarified specs.

Comment: For my own edification, why is this any faster than the original code? Aren't you still iterating through 2^N times?

Comment: @345243lkj The complexity is the same, but these arithmetic comparisons will be faster than creating lists of sets of ranges and `ANDing` them. Whether it is fast enough can only be answered by the OP.

Comment: Thanks Craig. I've tried this before, but it still takes time because of double loop...

Comment: @Fei-manHsu, it doesn't need to be O(nm) if you don't actually go through the entire sets in each level. If you can avoid needing to look at completely impossible items in the inner loop at all (as by bucketing and only evaluating buckets where there's possibility for overlap), you can make this much faster *even while having a nested loop*. So saying it's slow "because of the double loop" isn't the whole story.

Comment: The numerical solution seems incorrect. If `TEstart` is less than `gstart` and `TEend` is greater than `gend`, there is overlap, but your test would say that since neither appears _between_ `gstart` and `gend` the test fails. Assuming no empty ranges, I think a test like `if TEstart <= gend and gstart <= TEend:` would be both faster (1-2 tests per loop, not 2-4) and more correct (handling the four major cases, where `g` range encompasses `TE` range, `TE` encompasses `g`, `TE` overlaps `g` on left and `TE` overlaps `g` on right).

Comment: @ShadowRanger The code is based on the OP specs: "The aim is to find TE_id whose TEstart or TEend or both are located between gene_id' gstart and gend in each chr(key)."

Comment: @CraigBurgler: True, that's what they said. Their implementation disagrees though; that terrible `set` intersection check is just looking for overlapping ranges, not for the end points themselves to fall in that range, AFAICT.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes you are correct. We'll await OP's clarification.

Comment: @ShadowRanger and CraigBurgler, I've edited the post. The reason I use set is to find any overlapping ranges. Thanks for your notification and help.

Comment: @CraigBurgler, your code works fantastic. I got 49,772 records from 6,007 genes and 801,948 TEs in less than 1 sec. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using multi-threading, comparing code used for nested loop methods.

I created two csv's, one with 8k rows and one 800 rows of (int, float1,float2) random generated numbers and import as below:

```
import time
import itertools 

start = time.time()

def f((TE_id, TEstart, TEend)):
    a=[]
    for gene, gstart, gend in gfftree['chr1']:
        if (gstart <= TEstart <=gend) or (gstart<=TEend <=gend):
            a.append((gene,TE_id,TEstart,TEend))
    return a

'''
#slow
TEinTSS = []
for TE_id, TEstart, TEend in TElocation['chr1']:
    for gene, gstart, gend in gfftree['chr1']:
        if (gstart <= TEstart <=gend) or (gstart<=TEend <=gend):
            TEinTSS.append((gene,TE_id,TEstart,TEend))
print len(TEinTSS)
print time.time()-start

#faster
TEinTSS = []
for things in TElocation['chr1']:
    TEinTSS.extend(f(things))
print len(TEinTSS)
print time.time()-start
'''

#fastest (especially with multi-core, multithreading)
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p=Pool()
    TEinTSS = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(p.imap_unordered(f, b)))   
    print len(TEinTSS)
    print time.time() - start
```

Comment: Please comment with techniques to improve multiprocessing, very new to this!!

Comment: Don't pass an explicit worker count to `Pool`; by default `Pool` scales to available cores; this will leave cores unused when there are more than 12, and schedule more work than the machine can likely perform in parallel when there are fewer than 12 cores. Also, a minor optimization would be to construct `TEinTSS` as you go; if you can get away with being order insensitive, `TEinTSS = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(p.imap_unordered(f, a)))` would allow the main thread to be accumulating the results in a single `list` as the workers produced the results, instead of waiting, then combining.

Comment: Note that this is not multi-*threading*, but multi-*processing*. If you had tried multi-*threading*, you would've run into the GIL, which would prevent meaningful performance gains here. Multi-*processing*, however, is designed to bypass GIL-based limitations.

Answer (score 1):

If the aim of the process is purely to find the gene IDs falling inside a specific start range and *you're not too worried about how you achieve this but are simply looking for the fastest solution*, then you may want to consider dropping the concept of a loop altogether and looking at a pre-existing solution mechanism.

Assuming your data is in CSV format, the following would suit your requirements, returning a dataframe containing the IDs, gene names and associated chromasones, grouped by chromasone.

**File: genometest.py**

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['id', 'chromasone', 'start', 'end', 'gene_name']

te_locations = pd.read_csv('Sequences/te.bed', delimiter='\t', header=None, names=columns)
gene_locations = pd.read_csv('Sequences/gene.bed', delimiter='\t', header=None, names=columns)

dataframe = pd.merge(te_locations, gene_locations, on=['gene_name', 'chromasone'], how='outer', suffixes=('_te', '_ge'))
dataset = dataframe.query('start_te >= start_ge & start_te <= end_ge')[['peak_id_te', 'gene_name', 'chromasone']]
dataset.groupby('chromasone')
```

**Input sizes**

- TE_Locations dataset size = 337848
- Gene_Locations dataset size = 50307

**Output size**

- dataset size = 7085

**Performance**

```
$ python3 -m timeit 'import genometest'
10 loops, best of 3: 0.391 usec per loop
```